# GoogleCloudMessaging Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, unauthorized

I try to create project with use GoogleCloudMessaging  to recieve push - notifications from my remote server. 
For client i use google tutorial Implementing GCM Client. 
For server i use this realization on php, but after i started php script, i got an error:

Unauthorized

Error 401

Here is my php code:

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$serverApiKey = "778688687533"; // sender id (Project Number)
$reg = "APA91bFFWLYsX8TK_XiGQJeUkHb_7FJZwZBSdnNEdxzQEQ-ijpmVvwBPxaz3wQPmWy_K6YAIYt1x_3IBDzbyALxcpmjL8mKEX7g5CV9QpXod3oFp4Hm5HqsY8snoQdua3l0NcMoHm0WE4oTbNUYcbAOE7zjJEV_p9Q"; // registration id

$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization:key=' . $serverApiKey
);

$data = array(
'registration_ids' => array($reg),
'data' => array(
'message' => 'Hello, World!'
));

print (json_encode($data) . "\n\n");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
if ($headers)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print ($response);
```

[image][image]

Comment: You have to use server key!

Comment: Do i have to use server key instead of project number?
where can i get/create server key? google has changed disign of console, and i can't find server key. Thanks!

Comment: I solved the problem. As  Sunil Mishra wrote i had to use server key instead of sender id (Project Number) in my php script.

Comment: what do you mean "server key" ? I have the same issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create the new server key, follow the steps,

- Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/project
- Click your Project
- Go to **APIs & auth** on Left Panel
- Select Credentials in submenu on Left Panel
- Under **Public API access**, click on "**Create New Key**"
- Choose '**Server**'
- On next dialog, Specify the whitelisted IPs, if you have any. Leaving it blank, the requests will be from any IP
- Click **Create**.
- You will find the new server key is created under "**Public API Access**"

This key is to be used for sending message in your script on server side.