# Unauthorized (Error 401) Postman

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send Push Notifications (using Firebase platform) to my Android app through PostMan Chrome App, but I fail to make it work. I have followed all the instructions on connecting it, but it doesn't work. I can see that this is not an unusual problem, and therefore I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267372/googlecloudmessaging-unauthorized-error-401), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834020/sending-push-via-postman-using-firebase-messaging/38837582), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633188/firebase-401-unauthorized-error-fcm) and many more. Some console layouts/settings have changed and it's not that easy to follow ad literam, but I can see that the Authorization key is the secret.

However, even with all the check-ups and changes I have this: [image]

When I'm pressing on SEND to my app, it gives Unauthorized and Error 401. It is obvious what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. The Authorization key is the same both in the Firebase console and in the *.JSON file, while the body contains this:

```html
{
  "to": 
    "/topics/NEWS"
  ,
  "data": {
    "extra_information": "This is some extra information"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "NEW NOTIFICATION!",
    "text": "Click me to open an Activity!",
    "click_action": "SOMEACTIVITY"
  }
}
```

I even tried to add the key after `to:`

And extract from the JSON file can be seen below:
[image]
Nothing worked. Can anyone help me with this, please? Do I need to use some other code from the JSON file? Help?

Comment: Are you not on a network with a proxy requiring authentication? That could cause that error too

Comment: Interesting point, but I am not. Will try maybe to disable Firewall

Comment: Didn't work with disabling the Firewall

Comment: I’ve not seen `key=*` in an Auth header before. That doesn’t look right to me. Should it be something like `Bearer` then the key’s value?

Comment: Hmm. I will try with Bearer. I saw this in many tutorials, including this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heJmdX_djHs

Comment: With bearer, I get this *The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentication&quot; of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key specified in the authorization header must be the *Server key* or *Legacy Server key* shown in the Firebase console tab for *Project Settings > Cloud Messaging*.  The Web API key shown on the *Project Settings > General* tab will not work.

Also, the property for the notification text is `body`, not `text`:

```
{
  "to": 
    "/topics/NEWS"
  ,
  "data": {
    "extra_information": "This is some extra information"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "NEW NOTIFICATION!",
    "body": "Click me to open an Activity!", // <= CHANGED
    "click_action": "SOMEACTIVITY"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Bob. I just tried it, but nothing changed. I guess it's the Authentication method that creates these problems.

Comment: By the way, thank you for pointing this out. I had body in my code and text on Postman so I corrected it now.

Comment: For the value of the authorization key in the header, are you using the _Server key_ shown on the Project Settings/Cloud-Messaging tab of the Firebase console? I think either _Server key_ or _Legacy server key_ should work.

Comment: I have tried with both. I tried initially with the one in google-services.json (the one in the OP) and the one from Firebase > Project Settings > General where I also have the ID. The keys are, however, different. Should they be the same?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but in the first option (Authorization) in PostMan I have None. `Authorization Type: None`. I only have that key in the header

Comment: I just tried using Postman with your message body and a test project of mine.  The _Web API Key_ from the General Settings tab produced a 401 error.  Both the _Server_ and _Legacy Server_ keys from the Cloud Messaging tab worked.

Comment: Now I get it!!! I failed to see the Columns next to ”General” on Project Settings. It works like a charm. Can you please edit your answer by adding this so I can vote your answer? Thank you very much!